# VBA Open Multiple Blank Browser Tabs and Populate InnerHTML

Tags: vba, innerhtml, paste

My goal is to open a blank browser tab and populate it via innerHTML with .html code.  I'm successful with the first instance, but on the second (and thereafter), the blank tab is opened, but 'innerHTML' is posted to my first instance. I can't post in the newly opened blank tab.

Here is my code.  I've simplified.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim Ie As Object
    Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  
    Dim one As String
        one = "<title>one</title>"
    Dim two As String
        two = "<title>two</title>"

    With Ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "about:blank"
        .Document.body.innerHTML = one

        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "about:blank", 2048&
        .Document.body.innerHTML = two
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```vb
Public Sub Test()
    Dim Ie As Object
    Set Ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  
    With Ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "about:blank1"
        .Navigate "about:blank2", 2048&
    End With
    
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
    
    Set Ie = GetIE("about:blank1")
    If Not Ie Is Nothing Then Ie.document.Body.innerHTML = "<span>one</span>"
    
    Set Ie = GetIE("about:blank2")
    If Not Ie Is Nothing Then Ie.document.Body.innerHTML = "<span>two</span>"

End Sub


'get a reference to an existing IE window, given a partial URL
Function GetIE(sLocation As String) As Object

    Dim objShell As Object, objShellWindows As Object, o As Object
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim retVal As Object

    Set retVal = Nothing
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

    For Each o In objShellWindows
        sURL = ""
        On Error Resume Next  'because may not have a "document" property
        'Check the URL and if it's the one you want then
        ' assign the window object to the return value and exit the loop
        sURL = o.document.Location
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sURL Like sLocation & "*" Then
            Set retVal = o
            Exit For
        End If
    Next o

    Set GetIE = retVal

End Function
```